# Trouble playing sound from sony WH-1000XM4 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, sony

I'm having trouble using my wh-1000xm4s with ubuntu. It connects fine, but it won't show up in PulseAudio. The strange thing is that it worked previously, but after I disconnected it doesn't work any longer. Any ideas on how to get it working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I found out the answer. It seems like pulseaudio has troubles detecting that the headset is connected. For this you need to reset the bluetooth services;

```bash
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Then just reconnect the headset, and that should work!

Answer (score 11):

- Turn on the headphones
- Press the power button again and hold
- The headset switches off, do not release the button.
- Wait for it to turn back on in pairing mode. To release.

Then appears "WH-1000xm4" in the list of bluetooth devices, in addition to "THE_WH1000xm4". Select "WH-1000xm4".

Comment: I have tried that. And it says that it connects to the headset, but sometimes it won’t show up in pulseaudio, and will only play sound from speakers

Comment: This also solved a similar issue with WH-1000xm5.

Comment: In my case the ghost device was `LE_WH1000xm4`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what helped is:

1. Pulse Audio -> Configuration
2. Unchecking all the profiles except WH1000XM4 (WH1000XM3 in my case).

Answer (score 0):

When I have the headset connected via Bluetooth but not appearing in pulseaudio, I do the following:

1. Run in the terminal `pulseaudio -k`
2. Reconnect the headset

After that it gets recognized.